# replace line contents having / using sed

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, sed

Script looks as below

```
[Unit]
Description=Serial Getty on %I
Documentation=man:agetty(8) man:systemd-getty-generator(8)

Type=idle
Restart=always
UtmpIdentifier=%I
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```

Want to replace

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
with 
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty 9600 %I $TERM
```

Tried with these commands

```
sed -i 's/ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 110200,38900,9680 %I $TERM/ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty 9600 %I $TERM/g'
```

but it is not working due to presence of / in search string

Can anyone please help

Comment: Any reason not to use `systemctl edit` or create a drop-in configuration file? Why not just `s/ExecStart=.*/ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty 9600 %I $TERM/`?

Comment: This worked for me sed -i '/.*ExecStart=-*./c\ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty 9600 %I $TERM' file.sh. Thanks @KamilCuk

Comment: See ["Escape a string for a sed replace pattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) and ["Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Comment: `sed` doesn't require the use of `/` in the search and replace rule. You can use any character you want after the `s` and that character will become the separator. Ex: `s#pattern#replace#g`

Comment: Consider using `ed` instead of `sed -i` when editing a file. (`ed` is a file editor; `sed` is a *stream* editor based on `ed`, and some implementations add a non-standard `-i` option to edit files again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> replace line contents having / using sed
>
> [...]
>
> it is not working due to presence of / in search string

That's *one* of the reasons it's not working.  Your example also has a problem related to there being quotes embedded in the target text.

With respect to the `/` characters, there are several possibilities. The easiest one that serves the general case is to use a different character for the pattern delimiter.  `/` is most conventional for that purpose, but you can choose any character.  The `,`, `|`, and `#` are fairly common alternatives.  For example:

```
sed -i "s#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\\\u' --keep-baud 110200,38900,9680 %I \$TERM#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty 9600 %I \$TERM#" myunit.service
```

(Note: I removed the `g` option because it's moot: the pattern will not match more than once per line anyway.)

But that's a bit heavy-handed.  Your input has only one `ExecStart` line, so that's sufficient to identify the line to edit, and you don't need to replace the *whole* line.  I might instead use something like this:

```
sed -i '/ExecStart/ s/agetty.*/agetty 9600 %I $TERM/' myunit.service
```

That says: on each line matching pattern `/ExecStart/`, replace the longest substring starting with `agetty` with the string `agetty 9600 %I $TERM`.  That's crafted for your specific example, of course, but similar can be used on many other cases.

Comment: `@` is also an alternative pattern delimiter, which I found to be rather well-readable as it stands out from the "usual" pattern contents.

Answer (score -1):

sed 's/Hello/Greetings/' example.txt

This command uses the s (substitute) command to replace the first occurrence of "Hello" with "Greetings" in each line of the file. However, it doesn't modify the file itself;

Comment: That information is not related to this question.